# What is the canonical isomorphism for $T^k_l$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> What is the canonical isomorphism for $V^* \otimes V \cong L(V)$ for higher dimensions, namely, $T^k_l$? $T_1^1$ is defined to be $V^* \otimes V$, and similarly for $T^k_l$.

I learnt that the canonical isomorphism for $V^* \otimes V \cong L(V)$ is the linear transformation takes $v$ to $a(v)b$, where $a \in V^*, b \in V$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot see how the word "similarly" can be applied here, as I cannot see how the indices influence the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I think what you call $T_l^k$ (it would be good to have $V$ in the notation somewhere) is what is usually written $(V^*)^{\otimes l}\otimes V^{\otimes k}$ (or maybe with $k$ and $l$ interchanged, it is hard to read you mind from just the $k=l=1$ example).

In general, the space of $l$-linear maps from a vector space$~V$ with values in another space$~W$ is isomorphic to $L(V^{\otimes l},W)$ (the tensor product is more or less designed to make this isomorphism hold). Then combining the basic case $V^*\otimes W\cong L(V,W)$ (which as you say maps a basic tensor $f\otimes w$ to $v\mapsto f(v)w$) and the isomorphism $(V^*)^{\otimes l}\cong (V^{\otimes l})^*=L(V^{\otimes l},K)$, which maps a basic tensor $f_1\otimes\cdots\otimes f_l$ to the  function $v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_l\mapsto f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2)\ldots f_l(v_l)$, you obtain an isomorphism
$$
  (V^*)^{\otimes l}\otimes V^{\otimes k} \cong L(V^{\otimes l},V^{\otimes k}).
$$
This may or may not be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the multilinear linear maps

$$ (V^*)^{\Pi l-1} \times V^{\Pi k} \to V $$

The isomorphism $\text{Multilinear}((V^*)^{\Pi (l-1)} \times V^{\Pi k} , V ) \to T^k_l(V)$ should be similar to the case $k=l=1$. [what is a good notation for the space of multilinear maps?]

Edit: Define $\Phi:\text{Multilinear}((V^*)^{\Pi (l-1)} \times V^{\Pi k} , V ) \to T_k^l(V)$ by

$$ (\Phi A)(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^l,X_1,\ldots,X_k) = \omega^{l}(A(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^{l-1},X_1,\ldots,X_k)) $$

where we are identifying $T_k^l(V)$ with the space of multilinear maps $(V^*)^{\Pi l} \times V^{\Pi k} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi dc2814, could you give more details? I am really confused.

Comment: Thanks @dc2814 I was looking for this :)